# How to load image into varbinary column

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have table like this

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Product](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](100) NOT NULL,
    [Description] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL,
    [Price] [decimal](16, 3) NOT NULL,
    [SmallPhoto] [varbinary](max) NULL);
```

I want load image into [SmallPhoto] field

Main script looks like this

```
declare @filePath varchar(max)
declare @productId int

set @filePath = 'D:\myfile.png'
set @productId = 1

update Product
set SmallPhoto = -- some actions
where Id = @productId
```

Expected result

Command(s) completed successfully. :)

UPD:

1) My database located in other machine

2) I do not have opportunity to copy file to remote machine

Comment: Already answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3397484/sql-server-how-to-insert-into-varbinarymax-column

Comment: But now I have this problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2850205/cannot-bulk-load-the-file-c-data-txt-does-not-exist

Comment: Always good to search the archives before posting. Most times you will find your question was already asked and answered.